# Create Directory From Brother Directory

Tags: directory, mkdir

My directories have the following Format:
Inside the home directory, there are two directories: archive and production.

While inside the production directory I want to write a command to make a directory inside the archive directory.

Whats the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a relative path:

On Windows, from \home

```
 cd production
 mkdir ..\archive\newfolder
```

or
     `md ..\archive\newfolder`

On *nix, from /home

```
cd production
mkdir ../archive/newfolder
```

`..` means *parent* (up one level), and the *parent* (one level up) from *\home\production* is *\home*

Comment: What if I wanted to make the directory in archive from production/product1/sales/final?

Comment: Remember what I said about *up one level*? Repeat for each level. From `final`, it would be up three levels to `production`, so `../../../archive/newfolder`. To see it to figure it out, use `dir`, as in `dir ..`, `dir ../..`, `dir ../../..`

Answer (score 0):

from `/home` directory:

```
mdkir ../archive/$dirNameToMake
```